# Heavy tailed dataset for heavy hitters problem

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for datasets for evaluating algorithms for finding top-k on data streams ([e.g.](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwjptf2Us5XJAhUDhQ8KHRtRBPA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ficmi.cs.ucsb.edu%2Fresearch%2Ftech_reports%2Freports%2F2005-23.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG61wyb5JQGNgsLM7XWMgEcxvFmZQ&sig2=hKP4ZgaoP8HzRCv0XFTI4Q)).

I currently have network trace from [Caida](http://www.caida.org/home/), and some self-generated zipf i.i.d. distributed datasets.

I'm looking for real-life data sets which are *heavy tailed*, i.e., for any fixed `k`, the top-k elements only consists a small portion of the stream.

> **Any suggestions for available datasets for academic research which are used for streaming algorithms and are heavy tailed?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered in the OpenData SE

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Dawny33. Should I delete it and re-post it there? Can we migrate it? other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it can be migrated.  The moderator would look into this soon  :)